# Access is denied for WinJS.xhr Post?

Tags: javascript, http, winjs

I have been trying to post the form contents from inside of my windows 8.1 app to a php file on the server. However, I am keep getting an Access denied error:

> Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library code at line 4143, column 21 in ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.2.0/js/base.js
>
> > 0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.
> >
> > If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Below is my code:

```
$("#register_button").click(function (event) {


event.preventDefault();
var url = $("#registration_form").attr("action");
var type = "POST";
var username = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var firstName = $("#first_name").val();
var lastName = $("#last_name").val();
var data = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&email=" + email + "&first_name=" + firstName + "&last_name=" + lastName;
console.log(data);
WinJS.xhr({
url: url,
type: type,
data: data,
headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
})
.then(function (success) {
console.log(success.statusText);
}, function (error) {
console.log(error);
alert(error.message);
});
});

}));
```

Please tell me how to rectify this error, and if its there a better way or the correct way to do it. Just guide me how to do this.
Thanks :)

Comment: what do you get in your url variable ?

Comment: I get the values from the form control

Comment: is your content type valid ? try to debug your code, and post the value of each variable.

Comment: Yes, content type is valid. I am getting the values of all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The "alert" function is not authorised on HTML/Javascript Windows 8/8.1 apps

Comment: I made that function for my use.